# How do I change this sample rate conversion code to make the sound slower?

Tags: java, audio

For this assignment I need to take the helium class shown in the code below and transfer it so it becomes slower and deeper rather than higher pitched and faster

I've tried changing some of the int variables and no success

```java
public void helium(String sourceFile, String targetFile)
    {
        Sound sourceObj = new Sound(sourceFile);                                //Construct a new Sound object called sourceObj. A sourceObject now represents the sourceFile object.
        Sound target = new Sound(targetFile);                                   //Construct a new Sound object called target. The target object now represents the targetFile object.
        int sampleValue = 0;                                                    //The sampleValue variable is declare as an int and is initialized to 0.
        int targetIndex = 0;                                                    //The targetIndex variable is declared as an int and is initialized to 0.

        for(int index = 0; index < sourceObj.getLength(); index+=2)             //A for loop is created to traverse the length of the sourceObj. Notice that the loop increments by two each time, not 1.
        {
            sampleValue = sourceObj.getSampleValueAt(index);                    //The getSampleValueAt() method gets the sample value at index position of sampleObj.
            target.setSampleValueAt(targetIndex,sampleValue);                   //The setSampleValueAt() method sets the sample value at the targetIndex position in the target file.
            targetIndex++;                                                      //The targetIndex variable is incremented by 1 each time through the loop.
        }
        target.play();                                                          //The play() method is invoked on the target object to play the audio with the high pitched audio.
        target.write("heliumn.wav");                                            //The write() method is invoked on the target object and the audio with the new higher pitch is saved as a .wav file.
    }
```

The result should make the .wav slower and deeper sounding

Comment: Well I'd start by swapping the `<` for a `>` and the `++` for a `--`, and likely even the `+=` for a `-=`, and see what that does.

Comment: @jsarbour that is a terrible idea how would that do anything?

Comment: Do you understand what is happening in this loop and why it makes the pitch higher? you are basically getting every other value and saving it making there 1/2 as much data. See if you can insert duplicate data for every value to make the sequence twice as long

Comment: @mavriksc what do you mean by duplicate data? Like repeat the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about this from a purely acoustic standpoint. It's simple, and I'm sure you already understand how this works. Here's a 100Hz sine wave.

[image: 100Hz sine wave]

You can change the pitch of a sound wave by simply raising or lowering its frequency, right? So if we "compress" this sine wave by a factor of 2, we get a 200Hz sine wave, which sounds higher pitched.

[image: 200Hz sine wave]

What the sample code is doing becomes a little clearer with this in mind. For every 2 audio samples in the original sound, we write that sample to the new target sound. So we're *completely discarding* every other sample. That makes the sequence 1/2 the length, thus increasing its frequency and raising the pitch.

To lengthen/pitch down/decrease the frequency of the sound, you need to do the opposite, i.e. you need to *duplicate* the data at each sample point. Step through every sample rather than every two samples, and write that sample to the target two times.

This process is called [sample rate conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample-rate_conversion), and its namesake is pretty clear. Sample rate conversion is the simplest form of audio stretching you can perform.

Comment: thanks that really helped! finally got it working now!

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Here is a visual idea of what you want to do versus what it was doing originaly

Comment: [Here's another visual.](https://i.imgur.com/VWWQzq9.png) You might also consider "doubling" each sample's *position* rather than duplicating it. Not sure how to explain that well.